# docusignapi error calling UpdateNotificationSettings: { User Lacks Permission to resource

Tags: docusignapi

Using an demo account and my accountID, I am trying to change the Notification settings on an envelope I am creating using the REST API. I get the error below. Is this a settings issue with my account, or a problem with the way I am creating the envelope?

> Error calling UpdateNotificationSettings: {
>    "errorCode": "USER_LACKS_PERMISSIONS",
>    "message": "This user lacks sufficient permissions to access this resource."
>   }

Code:

```
Recipients recipients = new Recipients { Signers = new List<Signer>(signers) };
EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition
{
    EmailSubject = "Review and sign the document",
    Documents = new List<Document>(documents),
    Recipients = recipients,
    Status = "sent"           
};
ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
apiClient.Configuration.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient.Configuration);
EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelopeDefinition);

Expirations exp = new Expirations("14", "true", "2");
EnvelopeNotificationRequest enr = new EnvelopeNotificationRequest(exp, null, null);

string envelopeId = results.EnvelopeId;

envelopesApi.UpdateNotificationSettings(accountId, envelopeId, enr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're sending the envelope and then trying to change the expiration settings while it's live.

You might have better results adding that expirations to the envelope definition prior to the `CreateEnvelope()` call. Try this instead:

```
Recipients recipients = new Recipients { Signers = new List<Signer>(signers) };
EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition
{
    EmailSubject = "Review and sign the document",
    Documents = new List<Document>(documents),
    Recipients = recipients,
    Status = "sent"           
};

Expirations exp = new Expirations("14", "true", "2");
envelopeDefinition.Notification = new Notification(expirations)    

ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
apiClient.Configuration.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient.Configuration);
EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelopeDefinition);
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it